# How to do mean substraction and normalization over a batch of images in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a tensor of shape `[batch size, height, width, 1]` of grayscale images. First of all, I need to calculate mean and standard deviation values over all images in a batch (and save this values for later use). What are correct axis parameters in this case?

Then, I need to perform mean subtraction and normalization, also something like `X -= mean` and `X /= std`.

[tf.image.per_image_standardization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/per_image_standardization) is not an option because it works only on a single image.

Comment: Please, one question per post! "How do I calculate mean and std value over all images in batch?" is one question, I would say.

Comment: You want to calculate the mean and standard deviations of what, of which variable of the images?